# Google Drive iOS: Upload HTML file to overwrite an existing Docs file

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am trying to write an application that will pull down the contents of a Google Docs file as HTML to allow me to edit it inside the app. After editing the html file I then want to upload the changes back to Google Drive and update the contents of the original Google Docs file. I have been able to pull down the Google Docs file but am not able to upload my changes back to the server.

Can you please help to understand why this error is happening ? And possibly advise me on a fix for the issue ?

I am getting the following NSError:

```
    Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=500 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Internal Error)" UserInfo=0x157a8610 {error=Internal Error, GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0x16846f60: {message:"Internal Error" code:500 data:[1]}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Internal Error)}
2014-06-17 12:11:35.188 DrEdit[548:60b] Error UserInfo: {
    GTLStructuredError = "GTLErrorObject 0x16846f60: {message:\"Internal Error\" code:500 data:[1]}";
    NSLocalizedFailureReason = "(Internal Error)";
    error = "Internal Error";
}
```

Please code being executed when uploading below:

```
- (void)saveFile {
    GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = nil;

    // Only update the file content if different.
    if (![self.originalContent isEqualToString:self.textView.text]) {
//        NSData *fileContent =
//        [self.textView.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSAttributedString *s = self.textView.attributedText;

        NSDictionary *documentAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute, nil];
        NSData *htmlData = [s dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, s.length) documentAttributes:documentAttributes error:NULL];
//        NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:htmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//        NSData *fileContent = [self.textView.attributedText convertToData];
        uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html"];

//        [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:fileContent MIMEType:@"text/plain"];
//        [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:fileContent MIMEType:@"application/vnd.google-apps.document"];
    }

    self.driveFile.title = self.updatedTitle;
    GTLQueryDrive *query = nil;
    if (self.driveFile.identifier == nil || self.driveFile.identifier.length == 0) {
        // This is a new file, instantiate an insert query.
        query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:self.driveFile
                                            uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
    } else {
        // This file already exists, instantiate an update query.
        query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesUpdateWithObject:self.driveFile
                                                      fileId:self.driveFile.identifier
                                            uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
    }
    UIAlertView *alert = [DrEditUtilities showLoadingMessageWithTitle:@"Saving file"
                                                             delegate:self];

    [self.driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                              GTLDriveFile *updatedFile,
                                                              NSError *error) {
        [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
        if (error == nil) {
            self.driveFile = updatedFile;
            self.originalContent = [self.textView.text copy];
            self.updatedTitle = [updatedFile.title copy];
            [self toggleSaveButton];
            [self.delegate didUpdateFileWithIndex:self.fileIndex
                                        driveFile:self.driveFile];
            [self doneEditing:nil];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
            NSLog(@"Error UserInfo: %@", error.userInfo);
            [DrEditUtilities showErrorMessageWithTitle:@"Unable to save file"
                                               message:[error description]
                                              delegate:self];
        }
    }];
}
```

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by changing the property **convert** to YES on the GTLQueryDrive class. The documentation states that it will attempt to convert the file being uploaded into a native Google Docs format.

Hope this helps. Please see the method I am describing from the SDK below:

```
// Method: drive.files.update
// Updates file metadata and/or content
//  Required:
//   fileId: The ID of the file to update.
//  Optional:
**//   convert: Whether to convert this file to the corresponding Google Docs
//     format. (Default false)**
//   newRevision: Whether a blob upload should create a new revision. If false,
//     the blob data in the current head revision will be replaced. (Default
//     true)
//   ocr: Whether to attempt OCR on .jpg, .png, or .gif uploads. (Default false)
//   ocrLanguage: If ocr is true, hints at the language to use. Valid values are
//     ISO 639-1 codes.
//   pinned: Whether to pin the new revision. (Default false)
//   setModifiedDate: Whether to set the modified date with the supplied
//     modified date. (Default false)
//   sourceLanguage: The language of the original file to be translated.
//   targetLanguage: Target language to translate the file to. If no
//     sourceLanguage is provided, the API will attempt to detect the language.
//   timedTextLanguage: The language of the timed text.
//   timedTextTrackName: The timed text track name.
//   updateViewedDate: Whether to update the view date after successfully
//     updating the file. (Default true)
//  Upload Parameters:
//   Maximum size: 10GB
//   Accepted MIME type(s): */*
//  Authorization scope(s):
//   kGTLAuthScopeDrive
//   kGTLAuthScopeDriveFile
// Fetches a GTLDriveFile.
+ (id)queryForFilesUpdateWithObject:(GTLDriveFile *)object
                             fileId:(NSString *)fileId
                   uploadParameters:(GTLUploadParameters *)uploadParametersOrNil;
```

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: this is cool. I thought it was only possible to do on a new doc, not an existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to write html to a gdoc programmatically.
Currently its only possible to manually paste html but not with an api unfortunately (and strangely)

Comment: Thanks Zig. Do you know what the purpose of Revisions: patch section of the api is used for ? 

I was wanting to investigate if it would be possible to try and merge the changes the html changes into the existing google doc.

Comment: link to it, i dont see it in https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/

Comment: the only api I know that can edit google docs is https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app but that one doesnt accept html input either, you have to construct it through its edit api.